# Having trouble plotting histograms for continuous quantitative variables

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, visualization

I wanted to draw histograms(10 bins) for continuous quantitative variables within the **range of their values**. I've tried a few methods but the histograms don't look right.

- I want to use the columns 'pricesold' and 'mileage' to draw histograms.
- The 'mileage' column max is 350,000, and the 'pricesold' column max is 20,000.

The dataframe:
[image: The dataframe]

The code I've tried:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    x1 = df['pricesold']
    x2 = df['Mileage']

   plt.hist(df['pricesold'], bins=10)
   plt.hist(df['Mileage'], bins = 10)
   plt.hist([x1,x2], label = ['Price Sold', 'Mileage'], bins = 10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: As both variables have different ranges, it will be clearer to have them in separate subplots. Using matplotlib, you could try `fig, (ax1,ax2)=plt.subplots(ncols=2); ax1.hist(df['pricesold'], bins=10); ax2.hist(df['Mileage'], bins=10);`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest different approach

sample input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'priceold': [abs(random.gauss(150_000, 75_000)) for i in range(160)],
                   'mileage': [abs(random.gauss(10_000, 5_000)) for i in range(160)]
                   })
```

create new column for new bins:

```
df['mileage_bins'] = pd.cut(df['mileage'], bins=10).astype(str)
```

plotting in a prettier way:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.histogram(df, x='priceold', y='mileage', color='mileage_bins', width=600, nbins=10)
fig.show()
```

output:

[image]